# Como adicionar um objeto em uma posição aleatória de um NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c

Estou criando um array com a seguinte capacidade 15 deste modo:

```
meuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];
```

Porém quando tento inserir um objeto inicialmente na posição 10 deste modo:

```
[meuArray insertObject:algumObjeto atIndex:10];
```

recebo um erro dizendo que ultrapassei o tamanho do array:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 10 beyond
>   bounds for empty array'

Como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você inicializa o `NSMutableArray` com uma certa capacidade, isso é usado mais como uma "dica" para a classe de quantos elementos você pensa em armazenar (é o número inicial de objetos que o array pode armazenar, mas ele irá se expandir se necessário). Mas o array ainda está vazio após a chamada ao `alloc / init`, razão pela qual você não consegue inserir um objeto na posição 10.

Comment: Sim eu tava vendo isso, vi que a solução seria preencher o array com objetos temporários e substituir quando necessário.... o Ruim é que preciso compor um filtro, e no caso a parada ta complexa. Se tivesse como inserir isso deste modo, seria uma grande ajuda. Pois ajudaria mapear a posição das opções marcadas.... Mas to  dando um jeito com o uso de um dicionário.

Comment: Pois é, obj-c não tem suporte "first-class" para arrays esparsos, como uma linguagem tipo JavaScript. Dicionários seriam a melhor opção no seu caso.